# Intelij: how to change the syntax of extracted function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

When extracting a method in InteliJ typescript:

```
const main = () => {
  console.log(`say hello`);
};
```

The extracted method uses the following `function` syntax:

```
function extracted() {
  console.log(`say hello`);
}

const main = () => {
  extracted();
};
```

Is there a way to change the syntax that intelij uses to be

```
const extracted = () => {
  console.log(`say hello`);
}

const main = () => {
  extracted();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It is now available in IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm at the moment. Feel free to follow [WEB-26073](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26073).

However, you can press *Option(Alt)+Enter* on the extracted function and select *Convert to variable holding arrow function* after *Extract Method* refactoring.

[image]